# Codenameone Simulator in Intellij Community Edition drops network at random

Tags: codenameone

I am building an app with Codenameone using IntelliJ community edition on Mac running MacOS Big Sur . OF recent, when I am testing with the simulator, the network connection drops at random with a streams closed error message. I am lost for ideas on what could be the cause.

Comment: Do you have a callstack when the errors occur?
Is the network monitor open? What does it say?
Did you change something under the network option (there's an option to simulate a slow connection) ?
What JDK are you using? Ant or Maven?
Please add the answers into your question then comment here so I'll be notified that you made that edit.